# How to limit an element to zero or one in DTD with other unrestricted elements

Tags: xml, dtd

In a DTD I can see how in an element can be limited with zero or one by using the "?" symbol:

```
<!ELEMENT basket apple?>
```

But I also want to have no restriction on two other types of elements in the same sequence and the below does not seem to work?

UPDATED:

```
<!ELEMENT basket ((banana | coconut)+,(apple?),(banana | coconut)*>
```

So only one apple in the sequence but unlimited combination of banana and coconut. Any advice for a DTD novice? I'm aware about schema but our legacy app uses DTDs. Is is possible to enforce this via DTDs?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want zero or one `apple` with no occurrences of `banana` or `coconut`, try this:

```
  <!ELEMENT basket (apple?|(banana|coconut)*)>
```

If you want zero or one `apple` **and** zero or more occurrences of `banana` and/or `coconut`, try this:

```
  <!ELEMENT basket (apple?,(banana|coconut)*)>
```

Note this last example means zero or one `apple` *followed by* zero or more `banana` and/or `coconut`.

Comment: Basically we need to be able to have an number of banana and coconut elements and in any order but either zero or one apple element which can appear anywhere except as the first element. The apple can be the second or nth element.

Comment: @simgineer - There is probably a way to do this, but it's not coming to me right now. The closest I can think of is: `<!ELEMENT basket ((banana|coconut)+,apple,(banana|coconut)*)>`, but this makes `apple` required. If you try to make it optional (`apple?`) it results in an ambiguous content model (it's non-deterministic).